# Datatable data from array?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, codeigniter, datatable

I have a working Datatable at the moment that takes data from my tables directly. The thing is, now I want to populate an other Datatable using data from multiple table. I already have a working sql query that returns the data I want. What I was thinking of doing was to put each data of the columns I want in differents arrays, and then put them into the datatable.

```
$data = $this->log_send_model->getListDetailled($conditions,array('from'=>$this->uri->segment(4)),array('orderBy'=>array('id_log_send'=>'desc')));
$arrayMess = array();
   // Other array for columns

   foreach ($data as $value) {
      # code...
      array_push($arrayMess, $value->message);
      //var_dump($arrayMess);

}
```

Here, I want one column to be all the $value->message data. I was thinking of doing this for every column and then put it into the datatable.

Here is the Datatable code :

```
$(document).ready(function () {

$("#datatable").dataTable({
   processing: true,
    serverSide: true,
    ajax: {
        "url": "<?php echo base_url()."DatatableControl/dataTable"; ?>",
        "type": "POST"
    },
    columns: [
     { data: "id_log_send" },
     { data: "date" },
     { data: "recipient" },
     { data: "message" },
     { data: "etat" }
    ]
   })
});
```

As you can see, for each column I link it to a column of a table in the database. I want to put an array in these data options. Something like :

```
{ data: "$arrayMess" }
```

But it doesn't work.

How can I take data from the query, and put it into a Datatable ?

Comment: `{ data: "<?php echo json_encode($arrayMess); ?>" }` try this

Comment: When I do this I have an  “Unexpected token ILLEGAL”

Comment: then assign the value to variable like `var a ="<?php echo json_encode($arrayMess); ?>" ` and add `variable a` in array

Comment: It triggers the same error, token ILLEGAL.

Answer (score 0):

Data tables takes data in form of json so simply json_encode your array your task will be done

Comment: I did that, but when I do : { data: "<?php echo $arrayMess ?>" } I have 'Unexpected Identifier'

Answer (score 0):

I think you are following MVC architecture, then the function you are calling from view using ajax should return json formate output.

At Controller,

```
public function datatable(){
        $data = $this->log_send_model->getListDetailled($conditions,array('from'=>$this->uri->segment(4)),array('orderBy'=>array('id_log_send'=>'desc')));
        $arrayMess = array();
           // Other array for columns

           foreach ($data as $value) {
              # code...
              array_push($arrayMess, $value->message);
              //var_dump($arrayMess);

        }
      echo json_encode($arrayMess);
}
```

At view datatable part add this code,

```
    <table id="datatable">
      <thead>
         <tr>
           <th>id_log_send</th>
            <th>Date</th>
            <th>Recipient</th>
            <th>Message</th>
            <th>Etat</th>
         </tr>
    </thead>
    </table>
     <script>  
       $(document).ready(function () {
       if ( ! $.fn.dataTable.isDataTable( '#datatable' ) ) {
              var table = $("#datatable").DataTable();
            }
        $.ajax({
           "url": "<?php echo base_url()."DatatableControl/dataTable"; ?>",
            "type": "POST",
            success:function(data){
           $.each(data,function(i,item){
                        $('#datatable').dataTable().fnAddData( [
                            "<tr><td>"+item.id_log_send+"</td>",
                            "<td>"+item.date+"</td>",
                            "<td>"+item.recipient+"</td>",
                            "<td>"+item.message+"</td>",
                             "<td>"+item.etat+"</td></tr>"] );
                    });
           },error:function(error){ console.log(error);}
        });
});
</script>
```

I hope this will help you

Comment: I have a 500 internal error, "Uncaught TypeError: Argument 1 passed to CI:Exceptions.....".

Comment: When I use the dataTable method from the controller